# UITabBar look like UIToolBar (changing color of UITabBar)

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitabbar

Is it possible to make a UITabBar look like a UIToolBar, while maintaining its UITabBar-functionallity?
[Bottom to top http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/14763142/1eiof1.Skjermbilde%202010-06-20%20kl.%2022.29.13.png](http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/14763142/1eiof1.Skjermbilde%202010-06-20%20kl.%2022.29.13.png)

*Make the UITabBar (bottom) look like the UIToolBar (top).*

Thank you.

In addition to my question, I want to know how I can change the backgroundcolor of my tabBar. Is is possible? Does anybody have a library that subclasses the TabBar and changes its color?

Comment: What do you mean by "look like a UIToolbar"?

Comment: @Jeff: Have the design of a UIToolBar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making the UITabBar look like a UIToolBar, I would instead try making a UIToolBar have the functionality of a UITabBar- e.g. pressing on the buttons opens different subviews. Then, you could set the background color of the UIToolBar (it's actually listed as "Tint" in the properties).

Answer (score 1):

You might use images that look like toolbar buttons...

Have I understood your question correctly?
You want to change the look of tab bar's items so they will look like toolbar items?

Comment: Well, actually I just want to be able to change the color of the tab-bar… I know the UIToolBar lets you change its background-color, so I thought that might be the way to go.